# How not to run the build in Bamboo, if there are tests with an unspecified group

Tags: php, testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests, codeception

Developers and testers sometimes forget to specify a group for the test. I need to not allow the build to run in Bamboo if there are tests with an unspecified group. We specify the test groups in the test annotation. I have no idea how to do this. Perhaps this is due to my small experience. I will be glad to any help, thanks